# RSS reader with Instapaper or Readability integration?

Tags: software-recommendation, rss

One of my main information stream inputs is RSS feeds. Yet many link to long articles on strangely designed web pages, so I regularly read using Instapaper, or Readability.

Is there a RSS reader with built-in integration with Instapaper?

I want to quickly scan lots of feeds, and hit one button to send to Instapaper. Yes I know that I could use Google Reader, on a browser, with the Instapaper extension installed.

I find the web interface of google hard to scan quickly, and I would prefer an offline RSS reader.

thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Reeder](http://reederapp.com) (for both the iPhone and Mac OS) can send articles to Instapaper.

Comment: Reeder integrates Readability as well as Instapaper. And there's a beta of an OS X version, too.

Comment: Link to OS X beta: http://madeatgloria.com/brewery/silvio/reeder

Answer (score 3):

[NetNewsWire](http://netnewswireapp.com/mac/) integrates with Instapaper and also syncs with Google Reader.

Answer (score 1):

My favourite, Feedler, although only the [Pro](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/feeddler-rss-reader-pro/id365710282?mt=8) (paid) version supports Instapaper.

Answer (score 0):

There are LOTS of them. My favorites are:

[River of News](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/river-news-rss-google-reader/id386534091?mt=8) for iPad - $3.99.

MobileRSS for iPad/iPhone/iPod - Free/Paid versions.

Reeder for Mac - Free for now while in beta.

If you use Safari, [PureReader](http://nadesign.net/safari/) extension makes Google Reader webapp SOOO much nicer.

By the way, you didn't say which platform you're using.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently using [Gruml](http://www.grumlapp.com/), a slightly clunky but useful RSS reader for the Mac. It seems to support a lot of services, including Instapaper. It is also a beta and slightly buggy.

Comment: Agree on being buggy - shows promise though.